# Angular 7 - NavigationEnd and OnDestroy timing issue

Tags: angular, angular-router

We have just upgraded our project from Angular 6 to Angular 7 and are noticing the following issue where the NavigationEnd event is emitted before components are destroyed. Prior to upgrading to Angular 7 we were seeing the NavigationEnd event emit after components were destroyed.

Each instance of a WidgetContainerComponent subscribes to a configuration observable in the ngOnInit, and ngOnDestroy will unsubscribe it.

```
  constructor(@SkipSelf() private dataProviderDirective: DataProviderDirective) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("WidgetContainer.ngOnInit called");
    const _self = this;
    this.dataProviderDirective.getConfigurationPublisher().subscribe(widgetConfigurations => {
      _self.processConfiguration(widgetConfigurations, this.alias);
      this.subscribe(this.wsDataTopic + this.configuration.id, (message: Message) => this.onDataTopic(message));
      this.subscribe(this.wsStaleTopic + this.configuration.id, (message: Message) => this.onStaleTopic(message));
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("WidgetContainer.ngOnDestroy() called");
  }
```

Another component that houses these components (DashboardContainerComponent) has the following:

```
  navigationSubscription;

  constructor(@Host() private dashboardComponent: DashboardComponent, private router:Router) {
    super();
    this.navigationSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
      // If it is a NavigationEnd event re-initalise the component
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log("DashboardContainerComponent.onNavigationEnd()");
        this.initialize();
      }
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log("DashboardContainerComponent.ngAfterViewInit()");
    this.initialize();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.navigationSubscription) {
      this.navigationSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  private initialize(): void {
    this.publishConfiguration(this.dashboardComponent.getWidgets());
  }
```

What we are expecting to see is that upon navigating from one dashboard page to another, the existing WidgetContainerComponents on screen would be destroyed first, then the NavigationEnd event is triggered, causing the container to reload new widget configurations from the server. At the same time new WidgetContainerComponents are being recreated for the new dashboard page and subscribe to the containers configuration event.

However instead what we see is that the user navigates to a new dashboard, the navigation end is emitted, and the container emits the new widget configurations. Then the old widget container instances + the new ones are all trying to handle this event, and the old widget containers are erroring out because the data they are looking for does not exist (because they are not part of this page).

We're not sure if this is an intentional change in the timing of these life cycle events, but is there any thing we can do to prevent this situation from occurring?

Comment: "[T]here isn't a guarantee of the sequence of router events interleaved with component lifecycle hooks." If possible, try subscribing to data provided by the activated route.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17473#issuecomment-308848113